# Add field into an array element and keep the original structure

Tags: arrays, json, addition, jq

Hi I have an array of objects as input like

```
[{"keyA": "value"}, {"keyA": "otherValue"}...]
```

stored in bash environment variable. I want to keep the whole array but add/update the first element having the result like

```
[{"keyA": "value", "newkey": "newvalue"}, {"keyA": "otherValue"}...]
```

I've tried

```
echo $a | jq '.[0]+{"newkey": "value"}'
```

but the result is a single element of

```
{"keyA": "value", "newkey": "newvalue"}
```

```
echo $a | jq '.,.[0]+{"newkey": "newvalue"}'
```

but the result is

```
[{"keyA": "value"}, {"keyA": "otherValue"}...] {"keyA": "value", "newkey": "newvalue"}
```

How do I get the full array input set and with the first element updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an [update operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arithmeticupdate-assignment:+=,-=,*=,/=,%=,//=) there to retain the original structure and contents. For example:

```
.[0] += { newkey: "newvalue" }
```